# Exoplanet(s) that share orbit?

Tags: pluto, planet, exoplanet

Has Kepler (or any other survey) found an exoplanet with a similar orbit as another exoplanet around the same star?

The current IAU definition of a planet requires that "a planet has cleared its neighborhood around its orbit".

Have there been any exoplanet discoveries that bring such a definition into question?

Mathematically, is there anything stopping 2 "planets" from existing in equilibrium in a similar orbit around a single star?

Comment: What do you mean by "similar orbit?"

Comment: The IAU definition of "planet" is specific to objects that orbit our sun.  They do not attempt to include exoplanets within this classification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two planets sharing their orbit is expected to be a rare configuration. [Most configurations](https://www.quora.com/Can-two-planets-share-the-same-orbit) of 2 planets in 1 orbit are unstable. Only when one planet is in a Lagrange point of the other, are the orbits stable.

As of now (February 2017), there are [no known co-orbital planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-orbital_configuration). We do know lots of smaller objects co-orbiting with planets (in our own solar system, there are thousands of Trojans in e.g. Jupiter's orbit).

There was a potential detection ([Kepler-223](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler-223)), but on closer examination those planets were unlikely to be co-orbital.

Comment: Can't [horseshoe orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseshoe_orbit) not be stable (at least for a long time)?

Comment: Sadly, according to Wikipedia, "follow-up study of the system revealed that an alternative configuration, with the four planets having orbital periods in the ratio 8:6:4:3 is better supported by the data" -- i.e. what was thought to be a co-orbital situation appears not to be. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler-223

Comment: (Fascinating system either way -- 4 planets orbiting a star quite similar to our sun, but all four well inside Mercury's orbital distance!)